# Facebook app not working properly

Tags: php, facebook, header, location

I am writing a Facebook app, I would like to show the app only for facebook users and would like to get the user details. I have used the following codes

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => 'xxxxxx',
 'secret' => 'xxxxxx',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {

  try {

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}
else{

  $urlf= $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_status,publish_stream'));
  header("Location:".$urlf);
  exit;
}

if ($user) {
  $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
}
```

Here `$urlf` is giving the correct url, it is working well when I copy paste that url in the browser. But the header location is not working. This code is residing in the Canvas URL folder. Now the problem is that header location is not working. Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try catch is used to try something, and then if there are any errors resolve it properly. Your try has nothing in it, so it's worthless. That means nothing happens if `$facebook->getUser()` works.

You should sincerely read some books on programming PHP, because it's hard to tell what your code is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to guess without any error message, or indication of what's going on. But if your `$urlf` variable is correct, and if redirection is not happening it probably means that there is output **before** `header()` is called.

Make sure that `header()` is called before any output in the page, and it should work. If not you will need to debug your script and display PHP errors, using

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', -1);
```